# How to prove (P→¬P)→¬P when ¬ is primitive

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The logical connectives are → and ¬. Usable logical axioms, theorems and rules are

- A→(B→A)
- (A→(B→C))→((A→B)→(A→C))
- (¬A→¬B)→(B→A)
- ¬¬A→A
- A→¬¬A
- *modus ponens*.

Deduction theorem is also available.

I know how to do this if there were a falsum constant ⊥ and ¬P were defined as P→⊥. Assuming P and P→¬P I get ¬P:=P→⊥, then ⊥ is deduced from P→⊥ and the added premise P and finally P→⊥ results from the deduction theorem, cancelling P.

Now with ¬ being primitive, all I can get now is P,P→¬P⊢¬P and P,¬P⊢anything. I can't find a way to cancel the additional premise P. (P→¬P)→¬P should be provable because this system is complete relative to the usual truth value semantics.

Thanks.

Comment: Applying boolean algebra rules makes logic problems easy.

Comment: Do you have any rule (axiom or derived) concerning $\lnot(A\to B)$?

Comment: $¬(A\rightarrow B) \Leftrightarrow A \land ¬B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is quite tedious...

We have to prove :

> $\vdash (A \to B) \to ((\lnot A \to B) \to B)$ --- **(*)**.

With it, and the additional result : $\vdash A \to A$ --- **(§)**, we have :

1) $\vdash \lnot P \to \lnot P$ --- from **(§)**

2) $P \to \lnot P$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\vdash (P \to \lnot P) \to ((\lnot P \to \lnot P) \to \lnot P)$ --- from **(*)**

4) $\lnot P$ --- from 1), 2) and 3) by *modus ponens* twice

> 5) $(P \to \lnot P) \to \lnot P$ --- from 2) and 4) by *Deduction Th*, discharging [a].

---

Now for the proof of **(*)** above :

(A) 1) $A \to B$

2) $\lnot \lnot A$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\vdash \lnot \lnot A \to A$

4) $A$ --- by *mp*

5) $B$ --- by *mp*

6) $\vdash B \to \lnot \lnot B$

7) $\lnot \lnot B$ --- by *mp*

> 8) $A \to B \vdash \lnot \lnot A \to \lnot \lnot B$ --- by *DT*, discharging [a].

---

(B) 1) $A \to B$ --- premise

2) $\lnot \lnot A \to \lnot \lnot B$ --- from (A)

> 3) $A \to B \vdash \lnot B \to \lnot A$ --- from 2) and Ax.3 by *mp*.

---

(C) 1) $\vdash \lnot A \to (\lnot B \to \lnot A)$ --- Ax.1

> 2) $\vdash \lnot A \to (A \to B)$ --- from 1) and Ax.3 by *mp* and *DT*.

---

(D) 1) $\vdash \lnot A \to (A \to \lnot B)$ --- from (C)

2) $\vdash (\lnot A \to (A \to \lnot B)) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to \lnot B))$ --- Ax.2

3) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to \lnot B)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *mp*

4) $\vdash (\lnot A \to \lnot B) \to (B \to A)$ --- Ax.3

> 5) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (B \to A)$ --- from 3) and 4) by *mp* and *DT*.

---

(E) 1) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to A)$ --- from (D)

2) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to A)$ --- from $\vdash P \to P$

> 3) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to A$ --- from 1), 2) and Ax.2 by *mp*.

---

(F) 1) $A \to B$ --- premise

2) $\lnot A \to B$ --- premise

3) $\lnot B \to \lnot A$ --- from 1) and (B) by *mp*

4) $\lnot B \to B$ --- from 3) and 2) by *mp* and *DT*

5) $\vdash (\lnot B \to B) \to B$ --- from (E)

> 6) $A \to B, \lnot A \to B \vdash B$ --- from 4) and 5) by *mp*.

Now, **(*)** follows from (F) by *DT*.

---

---

*Added*

1) $A$ --- premise

2) $\lnot B$ --- premise

3) $A \to B$ --- assumed [a]

4) $B$ --- from 1) and 3) by *mp*

5) $(A \to B) \to B$ --- from 3) and 4) by *DT*, discharging [a]

6) $\lnot B \to \lnot (A \to B)$ --- from 5) by (B) above

> $A , \lnot B \vdash \lnot (A \to B)$ --- from 1), 2) and 5) by *mp*.

Comment: It is not necessary to prove the well-formed correlate of CCabCCNabb for this exercise.

Comment: I wonder how one come up with such a quite tedious proof.

Comment: What the exercise demands is actually A,~B⊢~(A→B). I'm able to get to A,~B⊢(A→B)→~(A→B). Now if ⊢(P→~P)→~P then ~(A→B) can be produced by modus ponens.

Comment: @gp120 If "demand" means "require", then the exercise doesn't demand either of the first two rules that you stated.  The exercise indicates an object logic theorem which can get proved using just your first three formulas and *modus ponens*.  I'm currently writing up such a proof.

Comment: Yes, a proof of A,~B⊢~(A→B) is what this exercise asks for. I guess there must be a relatively short one as the book is not about automated theorem proving.

Comment: @gp120 Before, by 'exercise' I believed you had meant your original problem as you had posed in your question.  Now I believe you mean what Mauro has referred to as ('star_symbol').  But, it is also NOT necessary to prove "A, ~B $\vdash$ ~(A$\rightarrow$B)" in order to show the ('star_symbol') formula.  That also can proven using just your first three formulas in the original problem statement and *modus ponens*.

Comment: I'll want to check it (and I want permission to put it up), but so long as OTTER is correct (I've never seen it fail at unification... though in an earlier version it has a soundness bug), it looks like a proof of the 'star_symbol' formula can get done as little as 32 detachments.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that i consider here is that $A \rightarrow B$ is true when A is false (or) B is true.

So, $p \rightarrow ¬p$ is equivalent to $¬p \lor ¬p \Leftrightarrow ¬p$

Comment: But this answer is not using $\lnot$ and $\to$ as the primitives.

Comment: Yes, the result is obviously true considering its intended interpretation. But this is an exercise on formal proof so I want to prove it using only → ¬ and axioms given.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we rewrite the definition of a formula such that we use Polish notation.  We might then consider the axioms as:

1 CxCyx  (A$\rightarrow$(B$\rightarrow$A))

2 CCxCyzCCxyCxz  ((A$\rightarrow$(B$\rightarrow$C))$\rightarrow$((A$\rightarrow$B)$\rightarrow$(A$\rightarrow$C)))

3 CCNxNyCyx (($\lnot$A$\rightarrow$$\lnot$B)$\rightarrow$(B$\rightarrow$A))

The goal of the exercise lies in proving:

CCxNxNx ((P$\rightarrow$$\lnot$P)$\rightarrow$$\lnot$P)

The following uses a diagrammatic technique to indicate a letter getting uniformly substituted with some other expression which satisfies the formation rules.  Two slanted lines indicate a use of the rule of *modus ponens* (I would prefer to use arrows, but I don't have the knowledge at present to do that).  Spacing gets used for purposes of display to make the substitutions clearer, but does not indicate part of the formulas.  In other words, as an example, C    $\alpha$ $\beta$ means exactly the same as C$\alpha$$\beta$.

```
2  CCx    CyzCCx    yCx    z
     |     ||  |    | |    |
     ----- ||  -----| -----| 
   CCCNxNyCyxCCCNxNyyCCNxNyx 3 CCNxNyCyx 
            \                  /
             6 CCCNxNyyCCNxNyx
```

6 CCCNxNyyCCNxNyx

```
2 CCxCyzCCxyCxz
       |      |
  CCxCyxCCxyCxx  1 CxCyx 
           \       /
         7  CCxy  Cxx  
               |
               ---
            CCxCyxCxx 1 CxCyx 
                \      /
             11  Cx   x  2 CCx  CyzCCx  yCx  z  
                  |   |      |       |    |
                  --- ---    ---     ---  ---
                 CCyz Cyz  CCCyzCyzCCCyzyCCyzz
                      \           /
                       CCCyzyCCyzz
                          |||  |||
                    12 CCCxyxCCxyy
```

12 CCCxyxCCxyy

```
                                 1 Cx        Cyx
                                    |         || 
                                    --------- |---------
                                   CCCNxNyCyxCzCCNxNyCyx 3 CCNxNyCyx 
                                                \          /
                                              8 CzCCNxNyCyx   
                 1 Cx          Cyx
                    |           ||
                    ----------- |-----------
                   CCzCCNxNyCyxCuCzCCNxNyCxyx 8 CzCCNxNyCyx            
                                 \             /
                                  CuCzCCNxNyCyx
                                   | |   | | ||
                             16   CxCyCCNzNuCuz
```

16 CxCyCCNzNuCuz

```
12 CCCx          yx          CCx          yy 16 Cx            CyCCNzNuCuz 
      |          ||            |          ||     | 
      -----------|-----------  -----------||     -------------
   CCCCyCCNzNuCuzaCyCCNzNuCuzCCCyCCNzNuCuzaa    CCCyCCNzNuCuzaCyCCNzNuCuz
                            \                  /
                             CCCyCCNzNuCuzaa
                                |   | | ||||
                       30    CCCxCCNyNzCzyuu
```

30 CCCxCCNyNzCzyuu

```
                               1 Cx          Cyx
                                  |           ||       
                                  ----------- |-----------
                                 CCCCxyxCCxyyCzCCCxyxCCxyy 12 CCCxyxCCxyy
                                             \            /
                             18               CzCCCxyxCCxyy
2 CCxCy     z    CCxy    Cxz      
    | |     |      ||     ||
    | ----- -----  |----- |----- 
  CCzCCCxyx CCxyyCCzCCxyxCzCCxyy              CzCCCxyxCCxyy 
                             \                /   1 CxCy  x     
                              CCzCCxyxCzCCxyx          |          
                                |      |               ---
                          33  CCxCCxyxCxCCxyx       CxCCxyx
                                      \             /
                                    93 CxCCxyx
```

93 CxCCxyx

```
                          1 Cx      Cyx    93 CxCCxyx 
                             |       ||        |  |||
                             ------- |-------  |  |||  
                            CCyCCyzzCxCyCCyzz CyCCyzz
                                   \         /
                               95   CxCyCCyzz        
2 CCxCyz    CCxyCxz
       |          |
       -----      -----                        
  CCxCyCCyzzCCxyCxCCyzz             CxCyCCyzz
           \                        /
             119    CCxy  CxCCy  zz    
                       |      |
                       ---    ---
                    CCxCyxCxCCCyxzz   1 CxCyx
                            \          /
                        160  CxCCCyxzz    
2 CCxCy    zCCxy    Cxz
      |        |
      -----    -----
  CCxCCCyxzzCCxCCyxzCxz      CxCCCyxzz
            \               /
         164  CCxCCyxzCxz
```

119 CCxyCxCCyzz

164 CCxCCyxzCxz

```
30 CCCx CCNyNzCzyu      u   164 CCx CCy  x  z  Cx  z
      |      | | |      |         |   |  |  |   |  |  
      --     | | ------ ------    --  -- -- --- -- ---
   CCCNxCCNyNxCxyCNxCxy CNxCxy  CCNxCCNy Nx CxyCNx Cxy
                       \        /
                   270   CNxCxy
```

270 CNxCxy

```
                 1 Cx          Cyx      
                    |           ||
                    ----------- |-----------
                    CCCxCCyxzCxzCuCCxCCyxzCxz 164 CCxCCyxzCxz
                                \                  /
                                  272 Cu    CCxCCyxzCxz
164 CCx    CCy x     z  Cx     z       |
      |      | |     |   |     |       |
      -----  | ----- --- ----- ---     -----
    CCCCyxzCCx CCyxz CxzCCCyxz Cxz    CCCyxzCCxCCyxzCxz
                        \            /
                         CCCyxzCxz
                            ||  |
                    4685 CCCxyzCyz
```

4685 CCCxyzCyz

```
                  4685 CCCx    yz      Cyz         
                          |    ||       ||
                          -----|------- |-------
                       CCCCNyNxxCCNyNxyCxCCNyNxy 6 CCCNyNxxCCNyNxy
2 CCxCy    zCCxy    Cxz         \                 /
      |    |   |      | 4730     CxCCNyNxy
      -----|   -----  |
  CCxCCNyNxyCCxCNyNxCxy          CxCCNyNxy
            \                   /
              4822 CCxCNyNxCxy
```

4822 CCxCNyNxCxy

```
              2 CCx CyzCCx yCx z
                  |  ||  | | | |
                  -- ||  --| --|
                CCNxCxyCCNxxCNxy  270 CNxCxy
                       \             /
                     279  CCNxxCNxy  
4822 CCx   CNyNx   Cx   y         |
       |     | |    |   |         |
       ----  | ---- ----|         -----
     CCCNxxCNxNCNxxCCNxxx CCNxxCNxNCNxx
                   \      /
               6579 CCNxxx
```

6579 CCNxxx

```
4685 CCCxy   z      Cy   z     2 CCxCyzCCxyCxz
        ||   |       |   |         | ||  || ||
        |--- ------- --- -------   | ||  || ||
     CCCzCxy CCzxCzyCCxy CCzxCzy CCzCxyCCzxCzy
                        \        /
                    4731 CCxyCCzxCzy
```

4731 CCxyCCzxCzy

```
4731 CCx   yCCzx   Czy
       |   |   |     |
       ----|   ----  |
     CCCNxxxCCzCNxxCzx 6579 CCNxxx
            \               /
     6614     CCz     CNxxCz     x       4685 CCCxy zCy z
                |       || |     |                | | | 
                ------  || ------|                --| --| 
              CCCCxNyyCNyyCCCxNyyy            CCCxNyyCNyy
                          \                   /
                      7112  CCCxNyyy
```

7112 CCCxNyyy

```
4731 CCx     yCCzx     Czy
       |         |
       ------    ------
     CCCCxNyyyCCzCCxNyyCzy  7112 CCCxNyyy
              \                  /
                 CCzCCxNyyCzy
                   |  | || ||
            7188 CCxCCyNzzCxz
```

7188 CCxCCyNzzCxz

```
93 Cx     CCx     yy  
    |       |     ||
    ------  ------||
   CCNxCxyCCCNxCxyzz  270 CNxCxy
          \              /
         278 CCCNx   Cx   yz      z       7188 CCx    CCyNzzCx    z
                 |    |    |      |              |      | || |    |
                 ---- ---- ------ -------        -----  | || -----|
             CCCNCxNyCCxNyyCNCxNyyCNCxNyy      CCNCxNyCCxNyyCNCxNyy
                                 \            /
                              15176 CNCxNyy
```

15176 CNCxNyy

```
119 CCx    yCx    CCyzz
      |      |
      -----  -----
    CCNCxNyyCNCxNyCCyzz 15176 CNCxNyy
             \               /
        15320  CNCxNyCCyzz
```

15320 CNCxNyCCyzz

```
6579 CCNx       x       x      15320 CNCx   NyCCyz  z 
        |       |       |               |    |   |  |
        ------- ------  -------         ---- |   -- --
     CCNCCxNxNx CCxNxNx CCxNxNx      CNCCxNxNxCCxNx Nx
                      \              /
                    17238   CCxNxNx
```

17238 CCxNxNx

I do not recall seeing an instance of CCNxxx getting used as the major premiss (the longer one) when using the rule of *modus ponens* before in the axiomatic context.  I feel rather surprised to see it happen *at all* in the axiomatic context, though perhaps this indicates something of the power of using an automated reasoning program as an assistant, since the above got obtained with the help of William McCune's program O.T.T.E.R. (originally developed at Argonne National Laboratory in the 1990s).

The above proof has 29 detachments (uses of the rule of detachment/the rule of *modus ponens*).  I did find some other proofs (hyper-resolution proofs which correspond to condensed detachment proofs) when searching for this one, but so far at least, I do not know of a proof which indicates that this can get done with less than 29 detachments for this theorem.  Though, perhaps a proof with fewer detachments can get found (using only the axioms that I used).